# API to get all categories and posts of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a [Codeigniter framwork](http://www.codeigniter.com/) project and I want all categories, all sub-categories, all post titles and post details of [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/).

Is there have any API that can give me all required data of WordPress which I can use in codeigniter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code i used before :

```
$XMLRPC_URL = "http://examle.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php";
    $BLOGID     = 1; // even if not WP multi site
    $USERNAME   = 'administartor'; // a user on requested wordpress, that user should have the desired permissions
    $PASSWORD   = 'password';
    $request    = xmlrpc_encode_request("wp.getTaxonomies",array($BLOGID, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD));
    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $XMLRPC_URL);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
```

I'm using (wp.getTaxonomies) to get all categories you can use what ever you want from here [XML-RPC WordPress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed,
This script i have to use in codeigniter, will it work there ?

Comment: I searched about XML-RPC WordPress API and got this example link https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/demo-sayhello/ . Actually i did not use any API till now so i don't know.                       Please navigate me how to use it.                                                 Thanks

Comment: Yes it will work directly, this code can work in any php platform the response will give you array with the list of categories if you want to get all posts you can use (wp.getPosts) instead of  ( wp.getTaxonomies ) .You can  see this page in case you need to use filters https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts

Comment: The link you got, i think it's more complicated to use in your case.

Comment: ok, so please tell me, i have to use your script, then can i use this file in controller of codeigniter ? and what should i keep its file name ?  
 And in $XMLRPC_URL what will be "wordpress/xmlrpc.php" ?        Thanks

Comment: Yes you can use it in controller  $XMLRPC_URL is : if your wordpress for example :example.com/  then you should put the url : http://example.com/xmlrpc.php

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for communicate. Now i keep your script in var/www folder(not in Codeigniter) and ran(i change url, username and password).
But it does not show anything. Code character length is long  so i cant put it on comment box

Comment: try : print_r(  $response );

Comment: do you have a fatal error because this function (xmlrpc_encode_request) ?

Comment: it does not show any error, just show blank page. My code is           <?php 
$XMLRPC_URL = "http://localhost/wp41/xmlrpc.php";
    $BLOGID     = 1; // even if not WP multi site
    $USERNAME   = 'admin'; // a user on requested wordpress, that user should have the desired permissions
    $PASSWORD   = 'admin123';
    $request    = xmlrpc_encode_request("wp.getPost",array($BLOGID, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD));
    $curlHandle = curl_init();

Comment: curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $XMLRPC_URL);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
    print_r($response);    
?>

Comment: Hello please help me, i searched a lot and now frustrated.

Comment: Please check if you have this function in your php http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php

Comment: i echo phpinfo(); and it show xmlrpc_errors is off. I informed client to enable it.  Thanks very much Ahmed for your help

Comment: Very Very Thanks Ahmed for your help.